mac zsh error : _omz_async_request:51: command not found: true
No matter what command I enter, it always pops up ‘_omz_async_request:51: command not found: true’. And ls command doesn't work.


From the wording of the error message, I guess that you are using oh-my-zsh. Can you check this?

Something has probably gone wrong with your PATH assignment. There are many posts here on SO about how to address this, including this one.
